# Runtime Error: Maximum Recursion Depth Exceeded when Using exit(0) in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm going through "Learn Python the Hard Way" by Zed Shaw.

I'm currently on lesson 36: http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex36.html

My issue:

I'm trying to create my own game based on what Zed did in lesson 35: http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex35.html

In his game he creates the following function to terminate the game:

```
def dead(why):
    print why, "Good job!"
    exit(0)
```

That's used in if/else statements such as this:

```
choice = raw_input("> ")

    if choice == "left":
        bear_room()
    elif choice == "right":
        cthulhu_room()
    else:
        dead("You stumble around the room until you starve.")
```

When I run his program it exits when calling the dead function.

However, when I try and use this same construct in my own code I get the following error:

```
RunTime Error: Maximum Recursion Depth Exceeded
```

after lines of code spitting out the spot in my program where the exit(0) function is called.

Here's an example of how I have used it in my program:

```
def exit(message):
    print message, "Your adventure is over."
    exit(0)
```

With if/else statements like this:

```
answer = raw_input("> ")

if "stay" in answer:
    exit("Adventure and excitement are only available to those who participate.")
elif "don't" in answer:
    exit("Great things were never achieved by cowards.  Please rethink your choice.")
elif "wait" in answer:
    exit("Great things were never achieved by cowards.  Please rethink your choice.")
elif "outside" in answer:
    exit("Adventure and excitement are only available to those who participate.")
elif "enter" in answer:
    lobby()
elif "go" in answer:
    lobby()
elif "through" in answer:
    lobby()
elif "inside" in answer:
    lobby()
else: 
    exit("Well, you're no fun!")
```

It's not clear to me why it works in Zed's program but doesn't in my own.  (And yes, I know that's probably an egregious use of elif's but my programming chops prohibit me from doing much else right now).

At first I thought it was due to how I was using while loops in my program but I've deleted all those and I'm having the same issues.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's pretty simple.  You named your function `exit()`, and your function tries to call a function named `exit()`.  Thus your function calls itself, then calls itself again, and again, and again...

When a function calls itself, this is called a *recursive* call.  If your function calls itself over and over too many times, eventually a limit is reached and Python stops your program.  Python raises an exception, telling you that the "maximum recursion depth" was reached.

Here's a simple fix:

```
import sys

def dead(why):
    print why, "Good job!"
    sys.exit(0)
```

Now your program is explicitly asking for a particular `exit()` function, the one inside `sys`.  Instead of calling itself recursively forever, it calls `sys.exit()` once and your program will stop.

Another solution is simply to rename your function to something other than `exit()`.  Zed called his `dead()` which is why his example works.